# Database Normalization precautions

Tags: sql, normalization

Okay. So at my place of work there is a products table in our sql database to hold information on our products (go figure). However the company that created the table (our former web vendor) apparently did not believe in using more than one table to hold the data. So what that amounts to is a 201 column table with a column for nearly every related and unrelated piece of data you can think of. Obviously, I don't want it to be like that anymore. I have created logical tables to divide the data into that contain the columns from the original. How do I go about populating the new tables with the data from the original? I know this is kind of a general question and I am looking for a general answer. I don't need specifics I just need to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: If you can point out one such sample data on how it is stored in product table and how you want to store in other logical table, people can help you out.

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag It is 201 columns so that might be a bit much to post a sample, but for example there are different clothing types with a different set of measurements for each type, I need to separate those.

Comment: yeah, so what is logical structure you have come up with and how is that clothingtype stored in main table. Only one column? or some related columns too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up database refactoring on the web.

Basically, don't create any tables or move any data. Instead, create SQL scripts that do the job in addition to an SQL view that recreates the original table layout virtually. Also some code that validates that view, probably by comparing the original table row by row. Then run the script, check the data, and when you have it exactly right, delete the monster table and rename the view to take its place.

Hopefully you do know about SELECT INTO to get the data into the new tables. You would do things like `SELECT DISTINCT clothingtype FROM bigtable INTO clothingtypes;`

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I found a product from Red Gate called Sql Prompt that does exactly what I need, I guess I wasn't googling the right words before ;). but yes I know how to do simple sql statements I just needed something to make this task a bit less daunting, my question was kind of worded badly.

Answer (score 0):

You select the columns you want to insert, for all or some of the rows from the original table, and insert this set into the destination table.  Are you familiar with the SQL UPDATE and INSERT statements? EDIT: You'd want to relocate only those columns that do not relate to *every* row; if the column pertains only to some rows, those rows/columns are candidates for relocation, if normalization is the goal.